# Transform points from one triangle to another triangle

Tags: c#

I have two triangles with the corresponding coordinates. Now I have to transfer further points from the first triangle to the second triangle. I've tried to solve it with emgu, but I have not found a way.
It is important for me that the points are transferred linearly.
Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this with C #?

Transformation between two triangles

[image]

Comment: There is a lot of information available on the subject of transformation of objects. Using a transformation Matrix is the answer.

Comment: Do I understand the triangles do NOT have the same shape? So the points should be positioned relative to the "deformed" triangle?

Comment: yes, the triangles do NOT have the same shape.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using homogeneous coordinates for the points A,B,C and A',B',C' and form the following transformation rule

[image: AffineTransform1]

To find the transformation matrix between the two triangles do the following

[image: solve]

Now for any point (x,y) the following transformation is valid

[image: AffineTransform2]

Comment: Thank you! I did it this way: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59468966/4723876)

Answer (score 1):

```
  //The following code is used to copy a triangular section contained in a bitmap image.
  //to trianglar section contained in another bitmap image.
  //The triangles differ in size, position, and orientation within the two bitmap images.
  //The triangular section is transformed in size, position, and orientation.
  //Boundary rectangles are used to rescale the transformed triangular section.
  //The boundary rectangle coordinates calculated from the maximum and mininum coordinates
  //of the two triangular sections.
  //The coeficients are calculated from the transformation matrix, and then used repeatedly
  //repeatedly in two simple equations to transform each pixel between the triangular sections
  //of the two images.
  //The transformation algorithm is carried out in reverse, which avoid pixel gaps in the
  //transformed image.
  //This has been successfully used to morph two images.  

    public void TransformFromTriangle1ToTriangle2()
    {
        //Coordinates of Triangle 1
        double x1A = Triangle1XA;
        double y1A = Triangle1YA;
        double x1B = Triangle1XB;
        double y1B = Triangle1YB;
        double x1C = Triangle1XC;
        double y1C = Triangle1YC;

        //Determine Boundary Rectangle coordinates containing Triangle 1
        
    //Minimum x1 coordinate
        double x1min  = x1A;
        if (x1min  > x1B) x1min  = x1B;
    if (x1min  > x1C) x1min  = x1C;

        //Maximum x1 coordinate
        double x1max  = x1A;
        if (x1max < x1B) x1max = x1B;
    if (x1max  < x1C) x1max  = x1C;

        //Minimum y1 coordinate
        double y1min  = y1A;
        if (y1min  > y1B) y1min  = y1B;
    if (y1min  > y1C) y1min  = y1C;

        //Maximum y1 coordinate
        double y1max  = y1A;
        if (y1max < y1B) y1max = y1B;
    if (y1max  < y1C) y1max  = y1C;
      
        //Coordinates of Triangle 2
        double x2A = Triangle2XA;
        double y2A = Triangle2YA;
        double x2B = Triangle2XB;
        double y2B = Triangle2YB;
        double x2C = Triangle2XC;
        double y2C = Triangle2YC;

        //Determine Boundary Rectangle coordinates containing Triangle 2
        
    //Minimum x2 coordinate
        double x2min  = x2A;
        if (x2min  > x2B) x2min  = x2B;
    if (x2min  > x2C) x2min  = x2C;

        //Maximum x2 coordinate
        double x2max  = x2A;
        if (x2max < x2B) x2max = x2B;
    if (x2max  < x2C) x2max  = x2C;

        //Minimum y2 coordinate
        double y2min  = y2A;
        if (y2min  > y2B) y2min  = y2B;
    if (y2min  > y2C) y2min  = y2C;

        //Maximum y2 coordinate
        double y2max  = y2A;
        if (y2max < y2B) y2max = y2B;
    if (y2max  < y2C) y2max  = y2C;

        //Ratio betwwen boundary rectangles
        ratiox = (x1max - x1min) / (x2max - x2min);
        ratioy = (y1max - y1min) / (y2max - y2min);

        // Calculate triangular transform coefficients in reverse (Triangle 2 to Triangle 1)
        coefA = (((x1A - x1B) * (y2A - y2C)) - ((x1A - x1C) * (y2A - y2B)))
                    / (((x2A - x2B) * (y2A - y2C)) - ((x2A - x2C) * (y2A - y2B)));

        coefB = (((x1A - x1B) * (x2A - x2C)) - ((x1A - x1C) * (x2A - x2B)))
                    / (((y2A - y2B) * (x2A - x2C)) - ((y2A - y2C) * (x2A - x2B)));

        coefC = x1A - (coefA * x2A) - (coefB * y2A);

        coefD = (((y1A - y1B) * (y2A - y2C)) - ((y1A - y1C) * (y2A - y2B)))
                    / (((x2A - x2B) * (y2A - y2C)) - ((x2A - x2C) * (y2A - y2B)));

        coefE = (((y1A - y1B) * (x2A - x2C)) - ((y1A - y1C) * (x2A - x2B)))
                    / (((y2A - y2B) * (x2A - x2C)) - ((y2A - y2C) * (x2A - x2B)));

        coefF = y1A - (coefD * x2A) - (coefE * y2A);

    //Transformation within the boundary rectangle coordinates containing Triangle 2
        for (int i = (int)x2min; i < (int)x2max; i++)
        {
            for (int j = (int)y2min; j < (int)y2max; j++)
            {
                x2 = i;
                y2 = j;

                //Determine coordinates of pixels to be copied from Triangle 1 from ratio between the boundary rectangles
                int m = (int)(x1min + ratiox * (x2 - x2min));
                int n = (int)(y1min + ratioy * (y2 - y2min));

                //Check coordinates (m,n) are within boundary rectangle containing Triangle 1
                if ((m >= x1min) && (m <= x1max) && (n >= y1min) && (n <= y1max))
                {
                    //Check coordinates (i,j) are within Triangle 2 (x2A,y2A),(x2B,y2B),(x2C,y2C)
                    double det = (x2B - x2A) * (y2C - y2A) - (y2B - y2A) * (x2C - x2A);

                    if ((det * ((x2B - x2A) * (j - y2A) - (y2B - y2A) * (i - x2A)) >= 0) &&
                        (det * ((x2C - x2B) * (j - y2B) - (y2C - y2B) * (i - x2B)) >= 0) &&
                        (det * ((x2A - x2C) * (j - y2C) - (y2A - y2C) * (i - x2C)) >= 0))
                    {
                        //Transform the coordinates from Triangle 1 to Triangle 2
                        x1 = coefA * x2 + coefB * y2 + coefC;
                        m = (int)x1;
                        y1 = coefD * x2 + coefE * y2 + coefF;
                        n = (int)y1;

                //Copy the pixel data from Triangle 1 into Triangle 2
                        Color pixelColor = Image1.GetPixel(m, n);
                        Image2.SetPixel(i, j, pixelColor);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the different transformations are translation, rotation, homothety

it seems the second triangle has increased in size (proportionaly), and has done a rotation and translation.

an idea what you could do:

1) check the size of each side of triangle (it has increased proportionaly ?)

2) check angles of triangle to check no modification

3) check the center of each triangle to see if no relation..

Comment: The second triangle can also change disproportionately.
As a background:
I make a drawing with 3 measuring points, glue the drawing on a plate, and then put it on my CNC milling machine. I then measure the measuring points and then have the coordinates of the second triangle.
Now I have to adapt all the curves I want to squeeze to the Second Triangle. Unfortunately, I have no math education and so I just can not get on with the problem.

Comment: its the reason i speak about center of triangle.

Answer (score 0):

You calculate the positions of the points based on the vectors `AB` and `AC` with the vector to `A` as the origin. The equation for one point would be:

```
P = A + r * AB + s * AC
```

The meaning of this is: "how far should I go along the `AB` line, and then go parallel along the `AC` line to get to the point `P`?" The values you calculate for `r` and `s` are between `[0,1]` since you will be inside the triangle. So when you calculate the factors `r` and `s` for a given point in the triangle, you can verify that the values looks okay when they are between `[0,1]`.

When you have calculated the factors `r` and `s` you can use them for the vectors of the new triangle. The equation will be:

```
P' = A' + r * A'B' + s* A'C'
```

You just copy the factors `r` and `s` over to the new equation of the triangle and you are done. Do this for all points and you have copied all points to the new triangle.

Answer (score 0):

have now found a solution. is certainly not quite the fastest way, but it works as far as I understand it:

```
double xA;
double yA;
double xB;
double yB;
double xC;
double yC;
double xA1;
double yA1;
double xB1;
double yB1;
double xC1;
double yC1;

xB -= xA;
yB -= yA;
xC -= xA;
yC -= yA;

xB1 -= xA1;
yB1 -= yA1;
xC1 -= xA1;
yC1 -= yA1;

double x;
double y;


double xnB = x / xB * xB1;
double ynB = xnB / xB1 * yB1;

double xnC = x / xC * xC1;
double ynC = xnC / xC1 * yC1;

double Ld = x / xB * yB - x / xC * yC;
double Ld1 = Math.Sqrt(((xnB - xnC) * (xnB - xnC)) + ((ynB - ynC) * (ynB - ynC)));

double npl = (Ld1 * (((x / xB * yB) - y) / Ld)) / Ld1;
if (double.IsNaN( npl))
npl = 0;
double x1 = (xnB - xnC) * npl;
double y1 = (ynB - ynC) * npl;

x1 = xnB - x1 + xA1;
y1 = ynB - y1 + yA1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  //To transform a PointA[] in TriangleA[] into PointB[] in TriangleB[].
  //Where TriangleA[] and TriangleB[] differ in size, position, and orientation.
  //The PointB[] is transformed in size, position, and orientation.
  //Provides two simple equations that can be used repeatedly to transform
  //points from TriangleA[] to TriangleB[]. 

  private void TransformPointAToPointB()
    {
        //Define TriangleA[], TriangleB[], PointA[] and PointB[].
        double xA1 = TriangleA[0, 0];
        double yA1 = TriangleA[0, 1];
        double xB1 = TriangleA[1, 0];
        double yB1 = TriangleA[1, 1];
        double xC1 = TriangleA[2, 0];
        double yC1 = TriangleA[2, 1];
        double xA2 = TriangleB[0, 0];
        double yA2 = TriangleB[0, 1];
        double xB2 = TriangleB[1, 0];
        double yB2 = TriangleB[1, 1];
        double xC2 = TriangleB[2, 0];
        double yC2 = TriangleB[2, 1];
        double x1 = PointA[0];
        double y1 = PointA[1];
        double x2 = PointB[0];
        double y2 = PointB[1];

        // The following coeficients have been derived from the transformation matrix, to be used
    // in two equations that calculate the position of PointB[] in TriangleB[], given the
    // position of PointA[] in Trianglea[].

        double coefA = (((xA2 - xB2) * (yA1 - yC1)) - ((xA2 - xC2) * (yA1 - yB1)))
                    / (((xA1 - xB1) * (yA1 - yC1)) - ((xA1 - xC1) * (yA1 - yB1)));

        double CoefB = (((xA2 - xB2) * (xA1 - xC1)) - ((xA2 - xC2) * (xA1 - xB1)))
                    / (((yA1 - yB1) * (xA1 - xC1)) - ((yA1 - yC1) * (xA1 - xB1)));

        double coefC = xA2 - (coefA*xA1) - (coefB*yA1);

        double coefD = (((yA2 - yB2) * (yA1 - yC1)) - ((yA2 - yC2) * (yA1 - yB1)))
                    / (((xA1 - xB1) * (yA1 - yC1)) - ((xA1 - xC1) * (yA1 - yB1)));

        double coefE = (((yA2 - yB2) * (xA1 - xC1)) - ((yA2 - yC2) * (xA1 - xB1)))
                    / (((yA1 - yB1) * (xA1 - xC1)) - ((yA1 - yC1) * (xA1 - xB1)));

        double coefF = yA2 - (coefD * xA1) - (coefE * yA1);

        // The following equations can be used repeatedly to transform points from TriangleA[] to TriangleB[]
        x2 = coefA * x1 + coefB * y1 + coefC;
        PointB[0] = x2;
        y2 = coefD * x1 + coefE * y1 + coefF;
        PointB[1] = y2;
    }
```