# Transform points from one triangle to another triangle. 3D version

Tags: matrix, geometry

Here is this question [2D version.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55546892/transform-points-from-one-triangle-to-another-triangle)
because I use unity3D,I have to transform points from one triangle to another triangle in 3D.

I have two triangles with the corresponding coordinates. Now I have to transfer further points from the first triangle to the second triangle. I've tried to solve it with emgu, but I have not found a way. It is important for me that the points are transferred linearly. Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this with C #?

Transformation between two triangles
[image: Text]

[2D version answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55550712/9293562) by [John Alexiou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/380384/john-alexiou)

Answer (score 0):

The approach is independent of the language: If you have a matrix `U` (and `V`) where each column contains the coordinates of one source points (and target points respectively). Then let `X` be the linear transformation that transforms the source points to the target points. This is the matrix we would like to recover. Then we have

```
V = U*X
```

where `*` is the matrix multiplication. This means we can simply compute

```
X = inv(U) * V
```

If `U` is not invertible, this means the three source points are not linearly independent, in that case you can still hope to recover a transformation `X` by using a pseudoinverse instead. But you should definitely check if `V - U*X` is as close to zero as possible. If this residual is large, you know that the transformation does not work out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify how the points of the first triangle are given. If we assume that they are known by local coordinates `(u, v)`, then in the source triangle,

```
P = A + u AB + v AC
```

and in the destination

```
P'= A' + u A'B' + v A'C'
```

And if the points are given by their 3D coordinates `(x, y, z)`, you have to solve the 3x2 system

```
P = A + u AB + v AC
```

for `u` and `v` and plug in the destination triangle. Using vector calculus,

```
AP x AB = u AB x AB + v AC x AB = v AC x AB
AP x AC = u AB x AC + v AC x AC = u AB x AC
```

and

```
(AP x AB).(AC x AB) = v (AC x AB)²
(AP x AC).(AB x AC) = u (AB x AC)²
```